# Excel VBA Dir() Error when file type changes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to better understand the `Dir` function. I have a `Dir` loop to take action on all `.csv` files in the directory, but when the loop comes across another file type, like `.txt`, it will error instead of moving on to the next `.csv`. item.

This is the relevant portion of my code.

```
strSourceExcelLocation = "\\rilinfs001\Interdepartmental\Billings & Deductions\Billing Coordinators\MCB Reports\East\Monthly Quality MCBs (CMQ & SECMQ)\2019\Individual_Reports\" & fldr & "\"

strWorkbook = Dir(strSourceExcelLocation & "*.csv*")

Do While Len(strWorkbook) > 0
    'Open the workbook
    Set wbktoExport = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strSourceExcelLocation & strWorkbook)

    'Export all sheets as single PDF
    Call Export_Excel_as_PDF(wbktoExport)

    'Get next workbook
    strWorkbook = Dir

    'Close Excel workbook without making changes
    wbktoExport.Close False
Loop
```

So if there are only  `.csv` files in the directory, then this works fine. When it comes across another file type, an error occurs.

The error is on line

```
strWorkbook = Dir
```

Run-time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument

Am I missing something with the way I use the wildcards in the `.csv` at the beginning?

Thank you

Comment: What error message or number are you getting?

Comment: You should either re-apply the same filter to get only the csv files, or add an `If` statement to skip any non-csv files that are found.

Comment: What's the name of the file which causes the error ?  I've never seen `Dir` ignore a filter.

Comment: @TimWilliams An example file name that works is "SECMQ0419045345D.CSV". An example that doesn't work is "SECMQ0419045345D.TXT". Every CSV file will have a corresponding TXT file.

Comment: @Mistella I get run-time error 5. Invalid procedure call or argument, on the `strWorkbook = Dir` line.

Comment: @TBoulz - have you tried my code below? If it works, consider changing `Call Export_Excel_as_PDF(wbktoExport)` to `Export_Excel_as_PDF wbktoExport`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my issue.

The problem seems to have been because when I called another procedure, I had another `Dir` in that sub to create a new folder if one didn't already exist. So basically I had a `Dir` in a `Dir`, which apparently is bad.

I moved the folder creation part to the very beginning of my procedure, so it is executed before I begin the `Dir` for looping through all the `CSV` files.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Loop_Dir_for_Excel_Workbooks()
Dim strWorkbook As String, wbktoExport As Workbook, strSourceExcelLocation As String, fldr As String, strTargetPDFLocation As String, d As String

strTargetPDFLocation = "\\nhchefs001\Accounting\IMAGING\BILLINGS & DEDUCTIONS\EAST MCB FILES\"
'***** Creating a folder to save the PDFs in. Naming the folder with today's date *****
d = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
strTargetPDFLocation = "\\nhchefs001\Accounting\IMAGING\BILLINGS & DEDUCTIONS\EAST MCB FILES\" & d & "\"
If Len(Dir(strTargetPDFLocation, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir strTargetPDFLocation

fldr = InputBox("Input the EXACT Folder Name that you want to create PDFs for")

strSourceExcelLocation = "\\rilinfs001\Interdepartmental\Billings & Deductions\Billing Coordinators\MCB Reports\East\Monthly Quality MCBs (CMQ & SECMQ)\2019\Individual_Reports\" & fldr & "\"

'Search all Excel files in the directory with .xls, .xlsx, xlsm extensions
strWorkbook = Dir(strSourceExcelLocation & "*.csv")

Do While Len(strWorkbook) > 0
    'Open the workbook
    Set wbktoExport = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strSourceExcelLocation & strWorkbook)

    'Export all sheets as single PDF
    Call Export_Excel_as_PDF(wbktoExport, strTargetPDFLocation)

    'Close Excel workbook without making changes
    wbktoExport.Close False

    'Get next workbook
    strWorkbook = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to hardcode the path and give it a try again. Probably the error is something really small in the hardcoding. E.g., in the code below, replace `C:\Users\username\Desktop\AAA\` with the path of the file. Then run it. Do not forget the last `\`. It should work:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim workbookPath As String
    workbookPath = Dir("C:\Users\username\Desktop\AAA\" & "*.csv")

    Do While Len(workbookPath) > 0
        Debug.Print workbookPath
        workbookPath = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code did work when I hardcode the exact folder into it, but I won't be doing that moving forward.

To give some more information, I edited my post to include what the string `strSourceExcelLocation` is. The string includes another string `fldr` which is determined through user input as it will always change and we won't always know the name of it in advance.

If it is not related to that string, then could it be something to do with the actions I'm having it perform during the `Dir` loop (edit the csv then save as PDF)?

Comment: @TBoulz - making something small work is the first part in the debugging process. Now try to add the `fldr` part in the code and make sure it works. Do not add the pdf part still.

Comment: Yes, I added the `fldr` in the same sub and it still worked. The path was printed to the immediate window.

Comment: @TBoulz - that's the way. So, if only the `CSV` path was printed tothe immediate window, then, you can concentrate on the 3 lines, related to the `Export_Excel_as_PDF` function.

Comment: My first action in the loop is to open the `CSV` file, which doesn't work with the one string `strSourceExcelLocation` because it returns the file name from the directory, but it needs the full file path. I was using `strSourceExcelLocation` and `strWorkbook` to open the file previously. In the test sub we have tried, we are left with `workbookPath` but that is not enough to open the file, I think?

Comment: I think I've found the cause of my problem. In the `Call Export_Excel_as_PDF(wbktoExport)` procedure, I use Dir again to see if a folder with today's date exists in a seperate location. So I think it is getting messed up because of a Dir within a Dir loop.

`If Len(Dir(strTargetPDFLocation, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir strTargetPDFLocation`

Comment: @TBoulz - well, give it a try. Or provide the code for the Export_Excel_as_PDF (and please, do not use &quot;_&quot; in the names of the procedures, they are reserved signs for events ☺)